# Reactor handle operator returns Object?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I want to use the `handle` operator, but the result of it is not the type I expect, it is always `Object`

```java
        Mono.just("lol").handle((string, sink) -> {
            if(!string.equals("lol")) {
                sink.error(new RuntimeException("not lol!"));
            } else {
                sink.next(2);
            }
        }).doOnNext(myInt -> { // expecting myInt to be an integer but is Object
            System.out.println(myInt);
        });
```

How can I get handle to recognize the type (similar to how `map` or `flatMap` recognizes the return type)?

Do I always have to use the `cast` operator?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use generics.

```
    Mono.<String>just("lol").<Integer>handle((string, sink) -> {
        if(!string.equals("lol")) {
            sink.error(new RuntimeException("not lol!"));
        } else {
            sink.next(2);
        }
    }).doOnNext(myInt -> {
        System.out.println(myInt);
    })
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves everything, especially the limitation of the `.cast()` operator